# C++ no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Node*’ to ‘Node*&’

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-search-tree, pass-by-reference

I am trying to use a recursive function to insert nodes into a binary search tree.  However, when I try to call my function, I get the error message

```
no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Node*’ to ‘Node*&’
```

This is the code for the recursive function and the function that calls it:

```
bool BST::add(int data)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        Node* gnu = new Node(data);
        root = gnu;
        return true;
    }
    return recursiveAdd(root, data);
}

bool BST::recursiveAdd(Node*& start, int data)
{
    if (start == NULL)
    {
        Node* gnu = new Node(data);
        start = gnu;
        return true;
    }
    if (data < start->getData())
    {
        return recursiveAdd(start->getLeft(), data);
    }
    if (data > start->getData())
    {
        return recursiveAdd(start->getRight(), data);
    }
    if (data == start->getData())
    {
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The following are the functions for getLeft(), getRight(), and getData() from my Node class:

```
 int Node::getData()
{
    return data;
}

Node* Node::getLeft()
{
    return leftChild;
}

Node* Node::getRight()
{
    return rightChild;
}
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could show me what I need to fix for it to work properly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your accessors return copies of the internal pointers

```
Node* Node::getLeft()
{
    return leftChild;
}

Node* Node::getRight()
{
    return rightChild;
}
```

But `recursiveAdd` needs to be able to modify the structure

```
start = gnu;
```

These approaches aren't compatible, and you were lucky the compiler caught you.  You can either change `getLeft()` and `getRight()` to return references, or capture the structure change made by `recursiveAdd()` and propagate it using a mutator.

```
Node* theLeft = start->getLeft();
bool did_insert = recursiveAdd(theLeft, data);
start->setLeft(theLeft);
return did_insert;
```

Or, as Matt says, you can make `recursiveAdd` a friend and just do

```
return recursiveAdd(start->leftChild, data);
```

Comment: I'll add in that having `getLeft` and `getRight` return references is rather pointless and it would be simpler to make `leftChild` and `rightChild` public (or make BST be a friend of Node)

Answer (score 1):

You can't bind a temporary variable (the copies returned by getLeft and getRight) with a non-const lvalue reference, hence the error.

You shouldn't need to modify the pointer itself anyway. I'd suggest you rewrite your algorithm to work without this rather strange and error-prone requirement.

Comment: How do you propose to change a tree's structure without modifying at least one of the pointers?

Comment: @Ben Voigt With setters ?

Comment: @Ben Voigt Yes of course, I meant modify it directly, by reference. You should use the interface provided by the class you're using.

Answer (score 0):

```
...
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        Node* gnu = new Node(data);
        root = gnu;
        return true;
    }
    return recursiveAdd(root, data);
}
```

Block scope. If `root` is NULL, you're going to end up with no declaration for `root` outside of the block. This means that `recursiveAdd()` will be called with an invalid parameter; this cannot compile or else it would always have the opportunity to yield undefined behavior.

**Regardless, since `root` will expire, so will the reference, as the reference will point to a temporary object. This is incorrect, as references cannot be bound to temporary objects--they, by definition, will point to "containers of values," often called *lvalues* in C++11 parlance.**

There are also *rvalues*, but that is outside the scope of the question.

Comment: Think about the lifetimes a little harder.